Flutter : Execution failed for task ':pusher_channels_flutter:verifyReleaseResources'
I'm working on a Flutter project with the following setup:
Flutter version: 3.24.1
Android compileSdkVersion: 34 (to meet Google Play Store requirements)
Package: pusher_channels_flutter: ^2.2.1
I'm able to build the app in debug mode without any issues, but when I try to build the app in release mode, I get the following error:
`FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':pusher_channels_flutter:verifyReleaseResources'.


A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.tasks.VerifyLibraryResourcesTask$Action
Android resource linking failed
ERROR: E:\Git Repo\RAQI\delivery_app\build\pusher_channels_flutter\intermediates\merged_res\release\mergeReleaseResources\values\values.xml:194: AAPT: error: resource android:attr/lStar not found.`

What I've Tried:

Verified that my compileSdkVersion is set to 34.
Cleaned and rebuilt the project with flutter clean and flutter pub get.
Ensured that all my dependencies are up-to-date.

Additional Information:

The error only occurs in release mode. The app runs fine in debug mode.
My Flutter project includes the pusher_channels_flutter package, which I suspect may be causing this issue.
Kotlin version is 2.2.20 (latest)
I need to keep `compileSdkVersion at 34 due to Play Store requirements.

Question:
Has anyone encountered a similar issue with the android:attr/lStar resource not being found during the release build process? Is there a workaround to resolve this issue while keeping compileSdkVersion at 34?
Any guidance would be appreciated. Thank you!

Where is the resource attr/lStar found?

@tomerpacific I don't know, it generates in the path
build\pusher_channels_flutter\intermediates\merged_res\release\mergeReleaseResources\values\values.xml

Seems like it is part of the pusher_channels package.

@tomerpacific yes I think so. Do you have any suggestions on how we can resolve this issue?

I have faced the same issue, after some diggin into the library I found out that this package depends on outdated maven repo:https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.pusher/pusher-java-client
so if you have intensions to keep your project up to date you should use something else since this repo has not been updated since 2022.
UPD: I have checked docs and it says JVM 17 is the latest supported version
UPD: I found solution in some of git threads but lost link to it..
got to .pub-cache->hosted->packages which causes problem and update compile and minimal sdk version. It is not best solution but It's needed until hoster will update theirs packages
